# How to set primary key - phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, laravel, primary-key

There are two types of products in my system, main products and other products.

In table 'products' I need to set the primary key as follows when adding a product:

```
main products id from 1,2,3,.....    
other products id from 1000,1001,1002,....
```

My problems are,

1. Can I do this in the primary key column by removing the Auto Increment method? and how?
2. If it is not possible in the primary key column then how can I do it?

ps: I use MySQL and phpMyAdmin to have the database

Comment: What happens when your catalog eventually needs more than 1000 main products?  Your design seems to be inviting problems later on.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The maximum number of main products will not exceed 100. That's why I used 1000

Comment: This depends on the database you’re using. Please tag it also. Some databases (like PostgreSQL) allow writing whatever to sequenced columns (its version of autoincrement), some don’t.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I use mysql in phpMyAdmin

Comment: You can simply define the primary key on ID(int) and insert yourself the ID value. But why don’t you use another field to distinguish main and other products?

Comment: @kiks73 thanks... But I need to get it in same column like this because thats how the client asked it.

Comment: @blackbird your client won't have access to the raw table data, will he?

Comment: @symlink hahaha i know... Now I set my database as adding another field to distinguish main and other products as kiks73 said...

Comment: @blackbird You may want to consider two separate tables with identical columns.